# weird filename sorting (bash, ls, sort)

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

Good day, everyone.

I'm trying to feed my music to mplayer, like this: `mplayer *`, but getting wrong track order.

Here's what I get with `ls` (as well as `ls -1`, `ls -1 | sort`), note the order of the numbers 'I', 'II', 'III' within concerts:

```
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: II.Largo e Spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: I. Adagio e spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: II.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: III.Larghetto.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: IV. Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: II.Largo.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: I.Adagio.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: II.Allegro assai.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: II.Largo.mp3
```

It seems, the sorting is performed by something like track name rather than track number, how would I tell bash to sort the files lexicographically?

Here is some more info that might be relevant:

```
$ LC_ALL=C type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ LC_ALL=C bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ LC_ALL=C ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

upd. I stored two first file names to files:

```
$ ls -1 | head -n1 > fname1; ls -1 | head -n2 | tail -n1 > fname2
```

then examined these two files with `meld` (`diff` GUI) to make sure there are no characters such as non-breakable spaces that could mess the sorting.
So… there are no such characters, there is no difference except for the clearly visible. Same for the second and the third file names.

Comment: The sorting order is correct. `sort` utility does not understand roman numerals.

Comment: I guessed, character . (dot) is less than I, so «I.» should be less than «II» — isn't it so? And «II.» should be less than «III».

Comment: Seems to ignore non-alphanumeric characters, therefore sorting "I" between Allegro and Largo/Larghetto. And it's correct for concerto 2, where I/II/III are named lexicographically, and IV sorts after IA, IIA, and IIIL.

Comment: Yes, looks like this. Is there a way to force sorting without ignoring any characters?

Comment: Change the locale applied to sorting. E.g. `LANG=C sort` is different from `LANG=de_DE sort`. You might even be able to patch your primary locale to behave differently.

Comment: Yes, found it at the same moment. Thank you :)

Comment: Similar to what Daniel suggested, you could see what output you get from `LC_COLLATE=C sort`. It should sort them in codepoint order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your locale temporarily for the duration of a command: I put your list of files in a file named `files`:

What you see:

```
$ LC_ALL='ru_RU.UTF-8' sort files
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: II.Largo e Spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: I. Adagio e spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: II.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: III.Larghetto.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: IV. Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: II.Largo.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: I.Adagio.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: II.Allegro assai.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: II.Largo.mp3
```

Sorted as you want:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort files
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: II.Largo e Spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.1 D-dur RV 549: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: I. Adagio e spiccato.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: II.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: III.Larghetto.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.2 g-moll RV 578: IV. Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: II.Largo.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.3 G-dur RV 310: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: I.Adagio.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: II.Allegro assai.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.4 e-moll RV 550: III.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: I.Allegro.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: II.Largo.mp3
Antonio Vivaldi - Op.3 concerto No.5 A-dur RV 519: III.Allegro.mp3
```

Specifically, you want to set the `LC_COLLATE` variable to `C`

Comment: Yes, my final solution was: `export LC_COLLATE=C; mplayer *`.

Answer (score 2):

As you already solved your issue (at least for roman numbers up to 8), this is a general remark:

`ls *` is not a good choice to check the file order as it get passed to your music player with `mplayer *`. That is because `ls` itself can rearrange the files -- and it is by no means guaranteed that the mechanism is the same as that used by the shell. *It depends on your settings.* Use `echo *` instead -- or for a prettier output `printf "%s\n" *`.

This example illustrates this with my personal alias `ls="ls -v"`:

```
$ touch 1 2 3 12
$ ls *
1  2  3  12
$ echo *
1 12 2 3
$ printf "%s\n" *
1
12
2
3
```

---

A much better solution is possible with `zsh`, but AFAIK not with `bash`:

Mikael Magnusson posted a [magnificent function](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00329.html) to deal with roman numbers on the zsh mailing list. Without going into details of the function itself this is how it works:

```
$ touch I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X L C D M
$ print *
C D I II III IV IX L M V VI VII VIII X
$ print *(no+romansort)
I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X L C D M
```

In the last print command`(no+romansort)`tells the shell, that you want to sort numerical (`n`) and use a custom function (`o+`) for parsing the filenames first.

This of course works, when the roman number is only part of the filename.
But be aware, that you need the `HIST_SUBST_PATTERN` option to be set!

Comment: Thank you, that's really interesting! May be one day I'll adopt zsh :)

// cannot upvote yet, I have too low reputation here.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, sort on Mac OSX (10.8.3) does sort the Roman numbers in the right order.

Nevertheless, what about first substituting the Roman numbers before feeding them to sort:

```
cat filename.txt | sed 's/IV/4/g' | sed s'/III/3/g' | sed 's/II/2/g' | sed 's/I/1/g' | sort
```

This worked for me (but again I tried this on OSX).

Comment: Seems too complex for me. I just want to perform `mplayer *` or something close to it and get my music. Of course, I can easily write smth like `play.sh`, but I'd like to avoid redundant complexity…